# How to align div elements irrespective of the length of text?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

```
<div>
   <button>Lorem ipsum</button> <span>20</span>
   <button>consectetur adipiscing elit</button> <span>30</span>
   <button>ABC</button> <span>40</span>
   <button>Something!</button> <span>50</span>
</div>
```

I want output screen to look like below:

```
Lorem ipsum                   20
consectetur adipiscing elit.  30
ABC                           40
Something!                    50
```

Comment: This is a `table`, use one.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS grid

```css
div {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0 10px;
  justify-items:start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Lorem ipsum</button> <span>20</span>
  <button>consectetur adipiscing elit</button> <span>30</span>
  <button>ABC</button> <span>40</span>
  <button>Something!</button> <span>50</span>
</div>
```